# Writing numbers and dates to file for use in other locales

Tags: c#, localization

My application creates various files (usually csv and text) containing dates and numeric values. Some of these files are intended to be opened by the user in Excel or Notepad, so it seems sensible to use "standard" .Net format strings like "F" for numbers and (say) "G", "D" or "T" for dates/times. This would presumably result in the values looking "correct" to the user.

However some files are intended to be read back in by the software, and it's feasible that a file created in one country could be sent to a customer in a different country, and loaded there. What's the best approach to handle this scenario? Is my only option to use a fixed "custom" format string when both writing and subsequent reading (parsing)?

Comment: Pick a format and write using that style. The only other way would be to save the format in the file too.

Comment: If it's going to be read always by your software store and read the data using `Culture.Invariant`

Answer (score 0):

For dates/times you should probably use either the [round-trip ("O")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#Roundtrip) or [RFC1123 ("R")](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings#RFC1123) format strings. That way it doesn't matter what culture is in effect when reading and writing.

Numbers are trickier: there's not much you can do other than agree on a format and ensure both readers and writers use it (unless using integers only). Simply because a floating-point number written out using one culture can be interpreted a different way when reading back in using a different culture (ie. some cultures use `.` as a decimal separator, whereas others use `,`).